# Cross domain issue - api different domain than frontend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, angularjs, cross-domain

I am not familiar with this issue and I hope you can help.
I am developing a web application. My Backend api endpoints sits under http://www.example.com/api where my front end application located in http://www.otherdomain.com.
The problem is that I get cross domain problems when I am trying to make ajax requests.
I am using AngularJS in the frontend and RoR (rails) on the backend.
Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What you're trying to do is, essentially, cross site scripting and is generally considered a no-no: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting .  You probably want to research JSONP to make calls to another domain or you want to build a server side proxy at otherdomain.com to access the API at example.com from the server [as opposed to the client].

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons browsers are blocking ajax request for another domain(you can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)). But you can try to use [$http.jsonp()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#methods_jsonp)

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this several times before in our PHP & Java Backend Api's. But our solution was always to include this to your api server header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Comment: Cool idea; but how exactly would one include this in their API Server header?  What sort of APIs were you exposing and in what method and with what technology?

Comment: We used this in our RESTFUL apis server this will fix your cross domain issue for sur . You could add this configuration through code or in your machine config. Don't know how though in RoR but I'm sure someone already did this. :D. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would probably be to set a `reverse proxy` using `nginx` so that the requests can be received by a local server, on your local domain, and reverse-proxied to the destination server exactly as they were received (CORS limitation do not apply on servers).

Another solution is this neat Javascript proxy:
https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain